# react-native-firebase Apple sign-in [Error: [auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.]

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a react-native app using Firebase, useContext with the react-native-firebase package.

My **useContext** is as follows:

```
import React, {createContext, useState, FC, ReactNode} from 'react';
import auth, {FirebaseAuthTypes} from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import appleAuth from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';

type UserContextType = {
  user: FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null;
  signUp: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  signIn: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  signOut: () => Promise<void>;
  resetPassword: (email: string) => Promise<void>;
  signInWithApple: () => void;
};

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>({
  user: null,
  signUp: async () => {},
  signIn: async () => {},
  signOut: async () => {},
  resetPassword: async () => {},
  signInWithApple: async () => {},
});

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const UserProvider: FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null>(null);

  const signUp = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password,
      );
      setUser(response.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const signIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      setUser(response.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const signOut = async () => {
    try {
      await auth().signOut();
      setUser(null);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const resetPassword = async (email: string) => {
    try {
      await auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const signInWithApple = async () => {
    try {
      // Check if Sign in with Apple is supported
      const isSupported = await appleAuth.isSupported();
      if (!isSupported) {
        throw new Error('Sign in with Apple is not supported on this device');
      }

      // Start the sign-in request
      const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
        requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
        requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
      });

      // Ensure Apple returned a user identityToken
      if (!appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken) {
        throw new Error('Apple Sign-In failed - no identity token returned');
      }

      // Create a Firebase credential from the response
      const {identityToken, nonce} = appleAuthRequestResponse;
      const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(
        identityToken,
        nonce,
      );

      // Sign the user in with the credential
      const authResult = await auth().signInWithCredential(appleCredential);
      const user = authResult.user;

      // Check if the user is new and update the display name
      if (authResult.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser) {
        const fullName = appleAuthRequestResponse.fullName;
        if (fullName?.givenName && fullName?.familyName) {
          await user.updateProfile({
            displayName: `${fullName.givenName} ${fullName.familyName}`,
          });
        }
      }

      // Return the user object
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{user, signUp, signIn, signOut, resetPassword, signInWithApple}}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserProvider;
```

I have implemented it by calling the context:
*const {**signInWithApple**} = **useContext**(UserContext);*

and then using signInWithApple inside a touchableOpacity

I have enabled SignIn on Firebase:

[image: Enable Firebase Apple sign in]

I have also enabled the capabilities within XCode:

[image: Xcode]

However, after following all of the implementation steps. I still receive the error:
**ERROR  [Error: [auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.]**

I thought that this might be because I was testing on a simulator? But I got my real device up and running and it seemed to be the same issue.
I also saw online that you have to fill in the service ID, but it looks like that should just be for Android.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!